# How should we handle pull requests into hotfix/* branches?

Tags: git, tfsbuild, devops, git-flow, octopus-deploy

TL;DR - How can I implement Pull Requests for a dynamically created branch?

---

We're using a modified [gitflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) workflow in TFS git, with the new TFS 2015 Build system for build and test, and Octopus for deployments.

We have the following set up:

- master - publishes a preview build to our INT servers
- release/v* - publishes a release build to QA -> UAT -> PREPROD -> LIVE
- feature/* - builds and tests code for features. Does not deploy to an environment.
- hotfix/v* - publishes a release build to PREPROD -> LIVE for urgent hotfixes

There is no develop branch. We branch hotfix/v* branches from tags that are created when we push to release/v* in order to hotfix a live environment. It all works really smoothly... until we implemented security on "master", and enforced Pull Requests for all branches except feature/* branches.

I have been asked to enable PRs on pushes to master, release/* and hotfix/* branches. Master is no problem - probably because it's a persistent branch; all three of the other branch types merge into master once work is done, and PRs work really well for this. I've used the TFS REST API to enable dynamic branch policies on newly created release/* and hotfix/* branches.

However, we are facing workflow issues when we try to enforce PRs for changes made to release/* and hotfix/* branches. These branches are dynamically created by the developer when they're required - the first push by the creator can include any changes, and those changes are then deployed to Octopus. For a release branch, this is generally OK because all we do is increment a version number in a file, and push the change. Any further changes to the release/* branch require the developer to create another branch off the release/* branch (let's say releasefix/v1.1.2), in order for them to create a PR into the release branch. This is a little awkward (and slightly dangerous), but an acceptable approach for us.

The problem comes when we want to PR a hotfix/* branch. The current workflow is as follows:

- Developer creates a branch from the release tag called "hotfix/v1.1.3", where the version is the LIVE version + 1 patch increment
- Developer makes changes to the hotfix branch as per the required fix
- Developer pushes the hotfix branch remotely, which then kicks off the build and creates an Octopus release. This release can be freely promoted to PREPROD and LIVE ***without*** a code review taking place.
- The hotfix/v1.1.3 branch is then merged into master, and any release/* branches currently in existence.

On top of the standard "Push Trigger" setting on a TFS build, TFS also has a code policy that allows us to run a build when the PR is created - but not ***after*** the PR is approved (apart from on the branch that the PR is being merged into). release/* and hotfix/* branches are usually merged into master, but we need to run the release build on both these branches after the PR is approved, not before!

Does anyone have any advice? The only idea I have is to scrap hotfix branches entirely, and maintain the latest live release/* branch, with hotfixes being merged into it. The problem we have there is that we would need to target a different lifecycle in octopus (PREPROD -> LIVE) for hotfixes, because QA and UAT may be in use by another release branch.

As a side note, we HAVE to use release/* branches, as we can have multiple releases going on at any point. This allows us to maintain separate bug fixes for different environments - going to the develop/master setup of gitflow won't work for us, and feels like a backwards step.

Comment: About the code policy,  there could be a way to achieve what you want. You can add a custom check-in policy which need a PR be approved before the check in . Detail ways please refer this blog [Creating TFS Custom Check-in Policy](http://blog.devart.com/creating-tfs-custom-check-in-policy-part-1.html). And then use the gated build check in.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We've decided to turn off PRs for hotfix branches, but I will definitely take a look at customising the PRs.